# Plotting a bode gain plot with the slope in Excel

Tags: transfer-function, matlab, low-pass, bode-plot, log

I am not an expert in Excel, and therefore, I want to know if there is a way of including the slope (dB/decade) in a bode gain plot in Excel or any free software (that allows to first input the frequencies and corresponding gain in dB, and then including the slope somehow)?

Comment: [This link](https://pages.mtu.edu/~tbco/cm416/freqexcel.pdf) should give you a start.

Comment: Not really answers the question

Answer (score 1):

Excel could be brow-beaten into this, given that it can represent an equation for your transfer function and process a list of data-result pairs.

Like here for example: http://www.engineers-excel.com/Apps/Bode_Plot/Description.htm

But... it's not going to choose the filter parameters for you, at least, not without a lot of back-end work.

This is probably closer to what you want: https://tools.analog.com/en/filterwizard/

Also relevant: [Are there good free software analog filter design tools? If not, why?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/148034/are-there-good-free-software-analog-filter-design-tools-if-not-why)

MORE:

The ask is to analyze Bode plot data and extract from that a transfer function. Ok, this may be relevant: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51695/is-there-a-way-to-obtain-the-transfer-function-from-a-bode-plot-on-python-i-kn

Comment: The reason I asked is because I obtained a list of data that I want to determine the transfer function from

Comment: Yah, I think that's a bit more than Excel can do on its own. You will probably need to do multiple sweeps over the variables and see which set 'fits' the reference best.

Comment: This might be more suited as a Python script. A taste of that: http://blog.analogmachine.org/2015/02/07/bode-plots-using-python/

Answer (score 1):

Excel plots can be easily done with detailed instructions, but [why bother when there are better tools](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%203%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%200%2028853.998118144256%0Aw%20264%20128%20248%20128%200%0Aw%20200%2064%20200%20128%200%0Aw%20304%20136%20304%20128%200%0Aw%20304%20128%20304%2064%200%0AO%20456%20128%20504%20128%200%0A170%20152%20128%20120%20128%202%2020%204000%205%200.1%0AB%20152%2032%20304%20312%201%20Box%0Ac%20200%20128%20248%20128%200%207.111562957856213e-8%200%0Ac%20200%2064%20248%2064%200%201.0000000000000002e-7%200%0Ar%20248%2064%20248%20128%200%204602.539168593712%0Aw%20248%2064%20304%2064%200%0Ar%20152%20128%20200%20128%200%20926.5486911693007%0Ar%20200%20128%20200%20216%200%20158.53004463686096%0Ag%20200%20216%20200%20232%200%0Aa%20264%20136%20304%20136%202%2015%20-15%201000000%0Ag%20264%20144%20264%20232%200%0AB%20304%2032%20456%20312%201%20Box%0Aw%20416%20128%20400%20128%200%0Aw%20352%2064%20352%20128%200%0Aw%20456%20136%20456%20128%200%0Aw%20456%20128%20456%2064%200%0Ac%20352%20128%20400%20128%200%207.111562957856113e-8%200%0Ac%20352%2064%20400%2064%200%201.0000000000000002e-7%200%0Ar%20400%2064%20400%20128%200%206578.041918860295%0Aw%20400%2064%20456%2064%200%0Ar%20304%20128%20352%20128%200%202733.833219128257%0Ar%20352%20128%20352%20216%200%20208.20647488397083%0Ag%20352%20216%20352%20232%200%0Aa%20416%20136%20456%20136%202%2015%20-15%201000000%0Ag%20416%20144%20416%20232%200%0A)

Prudent use requires you to scale the RC values in the optimal range, add non-inverting R's to balance bias impedance & voltages if low IR uV offset is desired.

Keep in mind the GBW of the Op is much greater than the simple 1st order low pass filter G*BW. It is also multiplied greatly by Q  of the pole & zeros, which is also computed in TI's Active Filter Software. (free)

In this hypothetical case, this filter needs a GBW of 1GHz, which you may see in a few years from now and the ideal response is shown in Red.

Choose Passive, Active any order and frequency.
 [image]

[image]

Comment: I think I have my system in the same software. Unfortunately, the plant cannot be determined (made as a black box) and I am trying to work out its transfer function. I did obtain a lot of measurements to work out the bode plots in excel. Now, I am stuck on using the plots to work the transfer function of the plant.

Comment: paste the formula here. It would be faster for me to do it than teach you

Comment: I'm done , where's your formula?